# Confusion on maven compiler plugin

Tags: maven-compiler-plugin

I am quite confused about maven compiler plugin and what it does. I have a project that has several modules. In my top pom.xml I have a section

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <configuration>
    <source>1.7</source>
    <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

My understanding is this specifies the JDK compiler version used to compile the code, and this section get inherited by all the modules. What I don't get is in my IntelliJ IDEA I can still specify project JDK in the settings and it seems like that setting overrides this. When I run maven install in the IDE I can confirm that it is using javac from JDK 8 to compile. So what does this section do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct; `maven-compiler` settings should be inherited by child modules.

I don't know about IntelliJ, but I can tell you that Eclipse picks&chooses whatever it wants from maven config, and for all the rest it uses its own settings.
Therefore, I'd expect IntelliJ may do something similar?

The simplest way to test this is to run a `mvn clean install` via command line, and see which "wins". If you get artifact compiled with 1.8 then it means you're missing something in Maven config which causes those settings not to propagate to children. If you get artifact compiled with 1.7 then it is IntelliJ who does it and not `maven-compiler-plugin`.

Comment: But I only have JDK 8 installed on my system. It seems like maven can still run fine even I set the version in the compile-plugin. So this plugin is useless??

Comment: JDK 8 _can_ compile sources targeted towards JDK 7 so it doesn't matter you only have JDK 8.
Plugin is not useless; if you were to want to run your build externally, without IntelliJ (for example for CI via Jenkins), then it would come into play.